# posting on Facebook page's timeline as admin is displaying in side bar (POSTS To PAGE) not on page wall(using PHP 4.0.0)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want to post on may Facebook Page's Timeline as Page admin using PHP SDK 4.0.0
Here is the sample code that I'm using

```
  <?php
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])&& isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] )){
       try {
            $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
            $request = ( new FacebookRequest( $session, 
              'GET', '/me' ) )-execute();
       $user = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray(); 
       $page_on_post='NMy PAGE ID';
       $requestonPage = new FacebookRequest($session,'POST',                  
                           '/'.$page_on_post.'/feed', 
                             array ('message' => 'This is a test message'));    
       $responseforPage = $requestonPage->execute();
       $graphObjectofPage = $responseforPage->getGraphObject();

       }
   }?>
```

when i added this code to my page it returns post id but it shows in sidebar not on timeline.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using a Page Token. If it does not post "as Page", you are most likely using a User Token only.

More information about Access Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: there is plenty of example code in the links i posted

Comment: Thanks.Its working .One more question i want to ask... for posting on multiple groups (timeline) i have to follow same procedure...means i have to get access token for groups also  .

Comment: you really should not post on multiple groups, that´s spam. but you would not get the required permission (user_groups) approved anyway, they rarely approve it.